# Calculating Time Complexity (2 Simple Algorithms)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, pseudocode

Here are two algorithms (pseudo-code):

```
Alg1(n)
1.    int x = n
2.    int a = 0
3.    while(x > 1) do
3.1.    for i = 1 to x do
3.1.1       a = a + 1
3.2     x = x - n/5

Alg2(n)
1.    int x = n
2.    int a = 0
3.    while(x > 1) do
3.1.    for i = 1 to x do
3.1.1       a = a + 1
3.2     x = x/5
```

The difference is on line 3.2.

Time complexity:

- Alg1: c + c +n*n*2c = 2c + 2cn² = 2c(n² + 1) = O(n²)
- Alg2: c + c +n*n*2c = 2c + 2cn² = 2c(n² + 1) = O(n²)

I wanted to know if the calculation is correct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below a formal method to deduce the order of growth of both your algorithms (I hope you're comfortable with Sigma Notation):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, I'm afraid you aren't correct.

In the first algorithm, the line:

```
x = x - n/5
```

Makes the `while` loop `O(1)` - it will run five times, however large `n` is. The `for` loop is `O(N)`, so it's `O(N)` overall.

In algorithm 2, by contrast, `x` decreases as

```
x = x/5
```

As `x = n` to start with, this `while` loop runs in `O(logN)`. However, the inner `for` loop also reduces as `logN` each time. Therefore you are carrying out `n + n/5 + n/25 + ...` operations, for `O(N)` again.

Comment: I think the number of operations in Alg2 should be `n + n/5 + n/25 + ... = O(n)`. Could you clarify this, since your answer is already accepted?

Comment: @trogdor yes, you're right - the inner loop in Alg2 *isn't* `O(n)`, as the length iterated over also falls off by `logN`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so overall O(NlogN)?

Comment: @Erez no, trogdor is correct, it's overall `O(N)`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Erez you can also prove the `O(n)` in Alg2 using the Master Theorem: the loop is a recurrence `T(n) = T(n/5) + n`. It is case 3 in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Answer (score -1):

**Algorithm 1** :
you decrease the value of x by `5` , so you do `n + n-5 + n-10 +....` which is `O(N^2)`

**Algorithm 2** :
you decrease the value of x by `n/5` , so you do `n + n/5 + n/25 +....` which is `O(N logN)`

see [wikipedia](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation&ei=YN4lU9iKOc2HrgfMuIHYDg&usg=AFQjCNFsPl2CW_acj-E5rq3PZ17cwqaJ2g&bvm=bv.62922401,d.bmk) for big-oh {O()} notation

Comment: You don't decrease `x` by 5, you decrease it by **`n/5`**

Comment: @jonrsharpe: i don't think that error could be reason for downvote ?